# operator ^ overload invalid operands of types ‘void’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am having this error from the code below. I have no idea how can I solve this problem. I tried multiple things like making functions void or auto or lambda functions to free functions. I tried all.

```
 invalid operands of types ‘void’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator|’
  145 |  student & func | OUTPUT;
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

```
emplate<typename Container, typename FuncObj>
auto take( Container cont, FuncObj fobj){
    Container result;
    for(const auto& item: cont){
        if(fobj(item)){
            result.push_back(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
template<typename T>
auto OUTPUT (T t){
    print(t);
}


template<typename Container ,typename FuncObj>
auto operator &(const Container& variable, const FuncObj& fobj){
    take(variable, fobj);

}

template<typename Container,typename FuncObj>
auto operator ^(const Container& container, const FuncObj& fobj){
    for(auto item: container){
        fobj(item);
    }
}
```

In main I gave this argument. Student is an struct.

```
student & func ^ OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Your operators don't return anything. That's a bit odd.

Comment: You cannot use `void` as argument to a function, so your operators (which return `void`) are not chainable.

Comment: Using the name of a template function without `<`template arguments`>` or `(`call parameters`)` is tricky, and only allowed in a few very specific circumstances. To get the syntax you want, probably `OUTPUT` should be the name of a class-type object which has a member function template `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename Container ,typename FuncObj>
auto operator &(const Container& variable, const FuncObj& fobj){
    take(variable, fobj);

}
```

This operator doesn't return anything so
`student & func ^ OUTPUT;` == `(student & func) ^ OUTPUT;` == `"void value" & OUTPUT`

There is no such thing as void value, so this code doesn't compile.

```
template<typename Container ,typename FuncObj>
auto operator &(const Container& variable, const FuncObj& fobj){
    return take(variable, fobj);
}
```

Would make more sense.

Note that passing `OUTPUT` won't work the way you expect. Your operator `^` expects a function, while `OUTPUT` is a function template. You need to use a functor or accept a template as template parameter.